# Fulltext index for a column with content in different languages

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I have a table containing contents from different languages. In order to enable full text search, I have followed the steps as below:-

- Enabled full text index with 'Language for word breaking' as 'English' for all columns
- I have used containstable query and specifies language_term as follows (in order to use Chinese word breakers and stammers),

  SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Table_Name,(Column_Name),'学校', LANGUAGE 'Simplified Chinese') http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx

But, the above query does not return any rows. If we change the default language for word breaking of the column to 'Simplified Chinese', the query will return rows.

Do we need to store the contents from different language to separate columns in order to achieve this?
Please help.